# Interpolate an SCSS(sass) variable inside an svg to change color

Tags: css, svg, sass

I'm trying to animate the state of an element, by changing the svg background color.

To be more easy I try to interpolate an SCSS(Sass) variable `#{$scss-variable}` inside SVG.

Off course is not working, probabilly need some form of encoding before, so I'm looking for an scss function that can do this.

```
.span {
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%
    2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20256%20448%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%20256%20448%22%3E%3Cstyle%
    20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E.arrow%7Bfill%3A@**#{$scss-variable}**%3B%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22arrow%22%20d%3D%22M25
    5.9%20168c0-4.2-1.6-7.9-4.8-11.2-3.2-3.2-6.9-4.8-11.2-4.8H16c-4.2%200-7.9%201.6-11.2%204.8S0%20163.8%200%20168c0%20
    4.4%201.6%208.2%204.8%2011.4l112%20112c3.1%203.1%206.8%204.6%2011.2%204.6%204.4%200%208.2-1.5%2011.4-4.6l112-112c
    3-3.2%204.5-7%204.5-11.4z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E%0A");

}
```

---

```
<span>aas</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would Export the SVG via Illustrator after expanding it.
[Here's an example of how to do that.](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-jpg-image-into-svg-in-adobe-illustrator)

Once you create the SVG, you can then add it into your HTML by actually including the SVG element directly in the HTML or render it with an image tag (I usually put it directly into HTML).

The SVG is made up of vector shapes. These shapes are called either `<circle>`, `<line>`, `<square>`, or `<paths>`.

To change the color of the path, all you need to do is target it with CSS and change the `fill` property of the element. If you want to change the outside lining of the element you edit the `stroke` and `stroke-width` attributes.

If you want to animate the color changing, you can do this using [keyframe animations as shown here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation2).